# delete a row with many rows in dependent tables

Tags: mysql, relational-database

I have a table lists. There are dependent tables with constaints like this:

```
CONSTRAINT `FK_list_id` FOREIGN KEY (`list_id`) 
  REFERENCES `lists` (`list_id`) 
  ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE.
```

For example, if I have for some list_id many rows in the child tables (100 of thousands or more) it takes a long time to delete it. Also, these operations can throttle the server.

How should I delete the list in this case? Should I not use `ON DELETE CASCADE`, but instead delete lists and then in the background delete the subscribers instead of deleting the list with cascade deleting of the child rows?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ON DELETE SET NULL` instead, and then later you can search for records where the FK id is `NULL` and delete those.

Comment: why would that be faster? `SET NULL` is still a write operation and would still be applied to all associated records, no?

Comment: The advantage of SET NULL is not quite clear. Maybe to use NO ACTION and put in queue item to delete rows with some list_id by chunks something like 1000 in background.